# node Stream from CSV, Transform, and Stream to TSV

Tags: node.js, csv, fs

I have a 1.4GB csv file that I want to go through row-by-row and parse each row. Once each row has been parsed, add that row to the stream and write the output as a tsv file. I thought the below code worked, but it simply adds each row to the end of the previous row without adding in line breaks as I expected. I also tried adding `.pipe(split2())` to the line before the `.pipe(writeStream)` to split the data before writing but that simply froze the application.

Has anybody been successfully reading and writing with this process in node?

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    _ = require('lodash'),
    split2 = require('split2'),
    through2 = require('through2');

fs.createReadStream('input_file_name.csv')
    .pipe(split2())
    .pipe(through2.obj(function (chunk, enc, callback) {

    // Process the CSV row
    var row = _.zipObject(['header1', 'header2', 'header3'], chunk.toString().split(','));
    this.push(processRow(row).join('\t')); // does an action to each row

    callback()
}))
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output_file_name.tsv'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Realized I was missing a good CSV parser, in lieu of simply splitting on `,`, as well as adding a `\n` to the end of each `data` string.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    _ = require('lodash'),
    parse = require('csv-parse'),
    transform = require('stream-transform');

var parser = parse();

var transformer = transform(function (record, callback) {
    var row = _.zipObject(['header1', 'header2', 'header3'], record);
    callback(null, processRow(row).join('\t') + '\n');
}, {parallel: 10}
);

fs.createReadStream('input_file_name.csv')
    .pipe(parser)
    .pipe(transformer)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output_file_name.tsv'));
```